# How to iterate a list over and over again?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a that will return a sequence of month names with Python.

For example, if I put:

```
gen = next_month('October')
lst = [next(gen) for i in range(15)]
print (lst)
```

I should get:

```
['November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',  'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January'])
```

But I get index out of range error with the following codes:

```
month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

def next_month(name: str) -> str:
    "Return a stream of the following months"
    global month_names
    month_index = month_names.index(name)
    while True:
            yield (month_names[month_index])
            month_index = month_index + 1
```

Just not sure how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: please consider formatting the code snippets you have added to your question. It may help other folks to see the issue clearly and try helping you out.

Answer (score 2):

itertools have a function `cycle`, that loops an iterator:

```
from itertools import cycle

month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

for month in cycle(month_names):
    print(month)
```

Homework edition:

```
def gen_cycle(l):
    cnt = 0
    while True:
        yield l[cnt]
        cnt = (cnt+1)%len(l)
```

Comment: Thank you! My apologies, I left out that I need to write a generator for this and can't really use any import tools...

Comment: updated, but you are not gonna pass exam by copying stuff of SO.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wasn't going to copy anything and I won't. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and just trying to get some guidance from experts. But I should have said it more explicitly. I am trying to learn and understand things not to copy things to get by. Thank you again.

Comment: Good luck on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not great for a homework answer but without hard coding the months you can use `itertools.count` and `datetime.datetime`:

```
def next_month(name):
    date = datetime.strptime(name, '%B')
    for m in count(date.month):
        date = date.replace(month=1+(m%12))
        yield date.strftime('%B')

gen = next_month('October')
print([next(gen) for i in range(15)])
```

This prints:

```
['November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']
```

This could also be done using a while loop although using count is a a shortcut